# 2 factor authentication to log in ODI and OBIEE 11g?

Tags: obiee, oracle-data-integrator

I have a requirement to integrate 2 factor authentication to log in ODI and OBIEE 11g. Has anyone implemented 2 factor authentication for ODI and OBIEE 11g?

Please suggest about how it can be achieved or work around to get achieve. Is it possible?

Thank you!
P.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question. In terms of OBIEE, it uses WebLogic Server authenticators, and there is detail [here of implementing MFA on WLS](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/idm/default-2030737.html) -- **but** that is for a standalone WLS application, not OBIEE. Almost certainly OBIEE natively would not work with something like this because it changes the UI flow from simple username/password. You'd have to probably look at brewing your own login page that then used the custom authenticator to let the user pass through to OBIEE (maybe piggybacking on the SSO/SAML functionality that is supported in OBIEE?). This is very speculative though...

Answer (score 0):

2-factor authentication is not available for ODI so far. And I'm not sure it will ever be the case, it would be too much trouble for your agent to connect to the repository every time it starts.